# why the sheaf of Y(O_Y), as a closed subscheme of X which is not necessarily affine, is quasi-coherent?

Tags: algebra, mit-scheme

In Hartshorne chapter 2, proposition 5.9. I get stuck with “Hence, J_Y, being the kernel of of a morphism of quasi-coherent sheaves, is also quasi-coherent.” in the proof. My question is why the sheaf of Y(O_Y), as a closed subscheme of X which is not necessarily affine, is quasi-coherent?

Comment: This question is not for this site. You should ask it in [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to Mathematics.